# How to specify mountOptions on an existing NFS share

Tags: kubernetes, statefulset

We're creating a kubernetes statefulset that is mounting a pre-existing NFS share.

Here's a trimmed down example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: StatefulSet
metadata: 
  name: hostname
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: container
        image: 4730230466298.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/container:latest
        volumeMounts:
        - name: efs
          mountPath: /efs
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: efs
        nfs:
          path: /
          server: 10.33.1.90
          readOnly: true
```

This works fine, and the nfs volume is correctly mounted into the container. But how can I specify the mount options on the the mount? I've tried setting the mountOptions parameter as shown here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#mount-options

on the volume and the volumeMount and it fails to validate. I don't need (or want) to create a PV or PVC because the nfs volume already exists outside of k8s and I just need to use it.

Is there anyway to specify the mount options?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding `PersistentVolumes`'s specs into `template.spec.volumes` (`Pos`'s volume).

These two are not the same thing. The correct reference for this `template.spec.volumes` would be https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/

You can create a [`PersistentVolume`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#mount-options) and [`persistenVolumeClaim`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims) with proper `mountOptions`, then you can use that `pvc` in the volume field in your above yaml.

Here is some example of [`nfs volume`](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/nfs) given by kubernetes itself.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a try and see if I can get it working. Will then follow up here.

Comment: The issue with the example given is that it uses the absolute minimal set of options and gives no reference to other options. If you're wanting to mount 2 NFS shares then its of no use at all.  If it included things like storage classes etc then it would make it a reasonable example